# Explode Function codeigniter not work

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'll just try to use explode function in tag system but its not work properly, first half is work but second half is not work, I'll explain my code and issue

```
Database structure : In a database structure  create a one col for tag storage
Tag Col : first_tag,second_tag,tag,third_tag
```

Now My Code is:

```
<?php
if(!empty($data)) {                                 
$str1=(explode(",",$data->tags));
$total=count($str1);}   
if($data) { 
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
{ ?>
<a href="#"><?php echo explode('_',$str1[$i]);?></a>
<?php   }} ?>
```

Result is :  First Explode function is Work Properly

```
  <a href="#">first_tag</a>
  <a href="#">second_tag</a>
  <a href="#">tag</a>
  <a href="#">third_tag</a>
```

But Second Explode Function is not work : I need This Structure

```
  <a href="#">first tag</a>
  <a href="#">second tag</a>
  <a href="#">tag</a>
  <a href="#">third tag</a>
```

This Structure I need, please check my code

Comment: can you show the dump of $data->tags ?

Comment: first_tag,second_tag,tag,third_tag [ This data fetch from database $data->tags ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something such

```
if(!empty($data)) {                                 
  $str1=(explode(",",$s));
  foreach($str1 as $str)
        { ?>
<a href="#"><?php echo str_replace('_', ' ', $str);?></a>
<?php   }
} ?>
```

Comment: bro one more q : <li class=" <?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'articles')echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>article/articles">Articles</a></li> , I'll try to add active class in navigation but this code is not work

Comment: `this->uri->uri_string()` returns full url `http://www.your-site.com/index.php/news/local/345`

Comment: if($this->uri->uri_string(3) == 'articles')echo 'active'; , in case 3 match with articles condition is true but active class not apply

Comment: if condition is true, you must see 'active' in output

Comment: it means the condition is false

Comment: Is there any other option in codeigniter to add active class in navigation

Comment: i don't know such method

Answer (score 0):

use preg_match instead like this

```
<?php
$data= "first_tag,second_tag,tag,third_tag";

if(!empty($data)) {                                 
$str1=(explode(",",$data));
$total=count($str1);}   
if($data) { 
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
{ 
preg_match( "/([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)/",$str1[$i],$matches);
?>
<a href="#"><?php echo $matches[1]." ".$matches[2]." ".$matches[3] ;?></a>
<?php   }} ?>
```

this will produce

```
<a href="#">first tag </a>
<a href="#">second tag </a>
<a href="#">  tag</a>
<a href="#">third tag </a>
```